# Fetching data axios

Tags: node.js, api, axios, inquirerjs

I am fetching data from an api and its response is something like this

```
{
    "id": "BTC",
    "currency": "BTC",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "1d": {
      "volume": "47854345429.71",
      "volume_change": "42758948175.92",
    },
    "7d": {
      "volume": "308524476736.00",
      "volume_change": "42758948175.92",

    },
```

Here, I am using inquirer to get specific option.. and I am trying fetch information for a specific interval i.e ( 1d, 7d, 30d,..) from an API

```js
    async volumechng(cmd) {
            try {
                keyManager = new KeyManager();
    
                const key = keyManager.getKey();
    
                const api = new CryptoAPI(key)
    
                const opts = await inquirer.prompt([
                    {
                        type: 'rawlist',
                        name: 'volumechng',
                        message: 'Volume change for interval ?',
                        choices: [
                            '1d',
                            '7d',
                        ],
                    }
                ])
                const volumeChange = await api.getVolumeChange(cmd,opts.volumechng)
    
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
```

```js
async getVolumeChange(coinOption,interval){
        try{
            const res = await axios.get(
                `${this.baseUrl}?key=${this.apiKey}&ids=${coinOption}`
            )
            let output = ''
            // console.log(interval) --> getting an output
            res.data.forEach(coin => {
                 output += `
                         ${coin.interval.volume_change}
                 `
            })

            return output
        }
        catch (err) {
            handleAPIError(err);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the value of interval on console.log() but I am not getting the output
[image]

Comment: What do you see if you take a look in the Network tab of your browser?

Comment: @LajosArpad I am making a CLI... so, I don't know how to see it in browser... for reference here is my git repo [here](https://github.com/Bhargav252000/crypto-info-command-line)
The issue is like if I don't pass the `opts.volumechng` , then it fetches perfectly everything from the url... but not when I pass  `opts.volumechng`  in `api.getVolumeChange`

Answer (score 0):

Let check:

1. `console.log('Data response', res.data)`
2. `console.log("Interval: ", interval)`

If you provide more output of them, I can help you more.

Please log to console too

```
res.data.forEach(coin => {
                 console.log("Coin ", coin)
                 output += `
                         ${coin.interval.volume_change}
                 `
            })
```

to check what your output is.

Comment: getting nothing... blank output.. Is this something to do with inquirer or else ?... If I dont pass `opts.volumechng`  in `getVolumechng`, it fetches perfectly.. and gives me coins name... but not when I pass

Comment: When you pass `opts.volumechng` as `interval` that is an object, not a string key name. So `coin.interval` can not get anything.
I'm pretty sure your call api get success data but when you  get `coin.interval.volume_change` is invalid.

Comment: Let check: 1. `console.log('Data response', res.data)`
2.`console.log("Interval: ", interval)`

If you provide ouput of them, I can help you more.